# valid proof of geometry for inner product of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I don't follow the last implication here: [![notes][1]]

How does for all $t \in [0,1]$
$$
\frac{t}{2} ||y||^2 + x^Ty \geq 0
$$
imply that $ x^Ty \geq 0$?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJM8o.jpg

Comment: Take $t = 0$, and you deduce the inequality.

Comment: Well, what happens when $t=0$? This would even hold if  $t\in (0,1]$ (why?)

Comment: @Matematleta I guess because $t^2$ goes to zero faster than $t$ in $[0,1]$?

Comment: @dunno Not sure exactly what you mean. How about doing it by contradiction? Suppose $ x^Ty < 0$, and then choose $t$ small enough so that..........

Comment: @Matematleta ahh i see, thanks!!

Comment: @dunno Glad to help....!!